# newly created template's templateDetails.xml is not working in joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla

I've created a joomla templates. As instructed I have placed my files and folders inside  and linked to css file in index.php but when I cut up all the text in templateDetails.xml it is still showing as previous in the browsers and also at positions even after doing a clean refresh. Why is it taking its position and css, I'm surprised.

**Edit**

as per comments I have been placing my templateDetails.xml contents

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE install PUBLIC "-//Joomla! 1.5//DTD template 1.0//EN" "http://www.joomla.org/xml/dtd/1.5/template-install.dtd">
<install version="1.5" type="template">
        <name>bini7a</name>
        <creationDate>Mon, Jun-10, 2013</creationDate>
        <author>Bhojendra Rauniyar</author>
        <authorEmail></authorEmail>
        <authorUrl></authorUrl>
        <copyright>Bhojendra Rauniyar</copyright>
        <license>GNU/GPL</license>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <description>bini7a: Bhojendra Template</description>
        <files>
                <filename>index.php</filename>
                <filename>templateDetails.xml</filename>
                <folder>images</folder>
                <folder>css</folder>
        </files>
        <positions>
             <position>headera1</position>
             <position>headera2</position>
             <position>mid</position>
             <position>headerb1</position>
             <position>headerc1</position>
             <position>headerd</position>
             <position>left</position>
             <position>right</position>
        </positions>
</install>
```

But even if I delete all these all the positions work correctly as defined position and also the css

Comment: instead of refreshing, try clicking the "save" button.

Comment: @Lodder no, its still happening.

Comment: What do you mean by `When I cut up all the text in templateDetails.xml it is still showing as previous in the browsers` ???

Comment: @AhmadAlfy it is still showing as previous styles with positioned. but it should not show the styles with the position if I remove all the text in templateDetails.xml

Comment: @C-Link I don't understand a word of what you are saying

Comment: when i remove the text from templateDetails.xml index.php should not link to styles and should not be positioned at thier positions.

Comment: that means templateDetails.xml is not working as it should.

Comment: You're not making much sense C-Link.  Edit your post to include the contents of your new template.xml contents.  It's not clear what you're doing by 'cutting up all the text'.

Comment: cutting up all the text means deleting all the text from templateDetails.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The positions specified within Joomla's `templateDetails.xml` are only really needed when configuring module positions within the administrator's Module Manager.  Once the position has been set it would appear the `templateDetails.xml` file does not need to be referenced again to display the module in that requested position.

To remove these positions permanently, either uninstall the template and reinstall with the new XML file or (the better) remove the positions from the template's `index.php` file.

You're looking for JDoc statements like the below:

`<jdoc:include type="modules" name="headera1" />`

See http://docs.joomla.org/Jdoc_statements for more information on the JDoc statements.

I hope this helps solve your dilemma.

Comment: That means I should reinstall the templates again. Thanks.